# Running flutter web app locally without android studio

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a flutter app using Firebase's cloud firestore. I've done the web build and running it on Chrome through Android Studio works well. I would like to share my web app progress to my client but don't want to host it (because it's not finished yet). Hence I'd like to find a way to run it locally the same way you can do it with Android Studio but without needing to install Android Studio (and hopefully not requiring to install flutter either), so that I can send the build file to my client and they can run it in their machine (with a script to start the web server locally and run the web app).

I have tried the following script included inside the web build folder (where the index.html is)

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from httplib import HTTPResponse
from os import curdir,sep

#Create a index.html aside the code
#Run: python server.py
#After run, try http://localhost:8080/

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path  = '/index.html'
        try:
            sendReply = False
            if self.path.endswith(".html"):
                mimeType = 'text/html'
                sendReply = True
            if sendReply == True:
                f = open(curdir + sep + self.path)
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', mimeType)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                f.close()
            return
        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File not found!')


def run():
    print('http server is starting...')
    #by default http server port is 80
    server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8080)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, RequestHandler)
    try:
        print 'http server is running...'
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        httpd.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

But when opening `http://localhost:8000` on Chrome I get a blanc page and the console shows the errors:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE main.dart.js:1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE manifest.json:1 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE :8080/favicon.png:1
```

I also tried NPM [local-web-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server) by running `ws --spa index.html` but just getting a `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` response.

This is what I have in my `build/web` after running `flutter build web`:

[image: build web folder files]

How can I create a local server where I can host my web app locally and run it locally without hosting it on the internet?

Comment: why do you need a server to do that? opening the index.html is enough right? or check this express tutorial https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html (not python though)

Comment: No, just opening index.html throws the error `Access to internal resource at 'file:///manifest.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.`

Comment: If you believe express is a solution, would you mind writing it down on how to implement it to make my flutter web app run using it?

Comment: if you are okay with dart just look into HttpServer class

Comment: I build the web app (flutter build web) and deploy its static contents to GitHub Pages or GitLab Pages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

as you mentioned in the comment here you go.

Create a file `app.js` with the following:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8000


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('getting request')
    res.sendFile('website/y.html',{root:__dirname})
  })

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/website'))

app.use((req, res)=>{
    res.redirect('/')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
```

Here my website files exist at `website` folder and my entry point is `y.html`.
Set the static file directory (your website page) and then serve the .html for the root request

Finally, to run it open terminal and move to the root folder. Then do

```
npm init
npm install express --no-save
node app.js
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the more simpler way. NO NEED to setup server**

open your Build/web folder in vscode.

install Live server Plugin in vscode.

[image: Live server plugin]

hit Golive Button
[image]

***Here you go your flutter web app would be running locally without android studio.***

Comment: You are missing the point in the question saying that this is so the client can run it. This solution won’t be an easy way for a client (who won’t have Vscode) to have to install a software, then install a plug-in, etc.. It could be a good solution for simply running the webapp though, however, I wouldn’t say it’s “a simpler way” from the requirements in question.

Comment: I found this solution easier than first one. Thanks @Gaurav Raj