# Running flutter web app locally without android studio throws firebase error

Tags: firebase, express, flutter, dart, flutter-web

After the successful installation of my flutter web app in a local server (following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65036882/3596898) by using express) I'm able to run my flutter app on localhost. However, upon accessing it, the console displays the error

`main.dart.js:28998 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined`

I presume that I need to install and reference firebase in my `app.js` but I actually have no idea how it's done (if this is actually the case). I tried running the command `npm install firebase` which seems to successfully install it however I'm still getting this error.

Do you know what I might be missing or why I am getting this error and how to solve it?

Note that the project works perfectly if ran on Chrome when built using Android Studio so it must be something to do with the local hosting.

---

**Edit**

This is my current index.html which is working perfectly when I run the project through Android Studio on Chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="App test">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="my_app">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>My App</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyGoogleMapsKey"></script>

  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.1.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
       https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

  <script>
    <!--  Your web app's Firebase configuration-->
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "apiKey",
      authDomain: "my-app.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://myApp.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "my-app",
      storageBucket: "my-app.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "2243255670923",
      appId: "1:3134567819932:web:f09e90ce142l9ikk0d2f27"
    };
    <!--  Initialize Firebase-->
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to include the overall firebase script and the services you're using in your `index.html` in the web folder. Do it **before** the
`<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>`
line in the body.

Note that even if flutter works well with the index.html as you have it, it's likely that this is the reason why it's not working on your local server.

In your case, move all the firebase related scripts (including the configuration script) before the `main.dart.js` script:

```HTML
<body>
  ...
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

  <script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "apiKey",
      authDomain: "my-app.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://myApp.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "my-app",
      storageBucket: "my-app.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "2243255670923",
      appId: "1:3134567819932:web:f09e90ce142l9ikk0d2f27"
    };
    
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>

  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is not the issue. I included these scripts where you mentioned and I'm still getting the same error. I don't see why I would need to include them anyways since I didn't have them originally and as I stated the project works perfectly if I run it through Android Studio on Chrome. If you can think of anything else that might be missing please let me know

Comment: @RedDeath You need to share your code. No one is going to be able to effectively help you without doing that. Even this answer was speculation. Share your `index.html` and any relevant firebase initialization code.

Comment: totally right - I didn't think it would be necessary but fair point. Updated question with my index.html file

Comment: Again, please note that the index.html as it is works well when running `flutter run` from the cmd

Comment: As pointed out in the answer did you move the firebase scripts before the `main.dart.js` scripts?

Comment: @RedDeath Please address Abhilash's comment. You should also be using the same version of firebase in each of your scripts.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore thanks for your comment. So what do you suggest? The scripts are the ones defined by Firebase, not copy-pasted from any random website, so I don't understand why I should modify them. Moreover, why is the project running without problems if I do `flutter run -d chrome` but it's not working if I try to setup my own local server using express.

Comment: @RedDeath I'm not going to address your app working in a different context. There are clearly errors here. Just thoroughly read the answer and the comments here. You have to do these scripts before main.dart.js and the versions should be the same.

Comment: @AbhilashChandran Yes I did try moving the scripts before main.dart.js and still getting the same issue

Comment: @RedDeath Make sure you're doing **clean** builds. Not hot reloading. Additionally, the firebase scripts should be the *same* version.

Comment: So, I moved my scripts up before main.dart.js script and changed their versions so they all have `7.5.1` (placing all of them in version `8.1.1` throws an exception when running `flutter run -d chrome` which was not happening before). Then built my web again and hosted it using express and when opening localhost:8080 in my Chrome browser the Chrome console throws the exception `Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created  - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).`

Comment: @RedDeath You have to move your firebase configuration to before `main.dart.js` as well. **Everything** should be before that script. So move `<script>
    <!--  Your web app's Firebase configuration-->
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "apiKey",
      authDomain: "my-app.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://myApp.firebaseio.com",`... earlier.

Comment: Alright @ChristopherMoore, I should have recognised your experience from the very beginning so please accept my apologies. As a developer myself I thought 'if Flutter is able to run the code as is, why should I modify it?' and clearly I was wrong. I cannot guess how Flutter manages to make it work if all the scripts are after the "main.dart.js" but that was clearly the issue with the local server. Thank you very much for your patience and help :)